# How can I draw a letter shape with a video as a background on my website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to figure out how [this website](https://www.nurturedigital.com/) is made but I just cannot figure out how they've done this.

They are using a gif on their homepage. But, if you hover over one of the sections, "Production/ Creative", etc., it becomes clearer. How is this made? By Javascript?

They are using arrows as a slider. How is this made?

Last but not least - If you click on the arrows, you see that a shape is shown with a video in the background being played. I have been searching for hours but just cannot figure out how to draw that line.

Comment: Its just transitioning between an *overlayer*: `https://www.nurturedigital.com/img/home-gifs/home-hover-research.svg` (each one has its own) yes lots of js and css

Comment: That is a lot of very advanced frontend animation. Looking at the source code, they use [Greensock](https://greensock.com/). Though, if you want straight answers on this site, I'd suggest you focus on one thing at a time. Post a question specifically about the video letter shape, for example. That should get some really good responses.

Comment: mix-blend-mode https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/KNrMVE / https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/details/dyyXQeK  answer it belonged was deleted :(

Comment: Hi.

Thanks for the fast answers guys really!

So they are combining that overlay with a javascript hover- function? Did I get it right? 

And how could you figure out, that they are using Greensock?

And thanks for the mix-blend-mode hint!! That's it. But how can the video just being played in the letter shape? Because in the codepen section it is also played around the letters

Answer (score 3):

You can easily use a mask with a letter as a shape, to do this you can consider an SVG mask.

Here is a basic example. As you will see, the SVG is a basic text element. Simply adjust the font and the letter to what you want:

```css
video {
    height:300px;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-mask:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 13 13"><text  x="0" y="12" font-family="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" >A</text></svg>') center/contain no-repeat;
            mask:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 13 13"><text  x="0" y="12" font-family="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" >A</text></svg>') center/contain no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<video src="https://node-images-test.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/Pexels+Videos+2292093.mp4" autoplay muted></video>
```

You can also scale this to any number of letter by using multiple mask and adjust the size/position like you want:

```css
video {
    height:300px;
    width:500px;
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
    -webkit-mask:
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 13 13"><text  x="0" y="12" font-family="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" >A</text></svg>') left,
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 13 13"><text  x="0" y="12" font-family="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" >B</text></svg>') center,
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 13 13"><text  x="0" y="12" font-family="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" >C</text></svg>') right;
    -webkit-mask-size:33% auto;
    -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
            mask:
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 13 13"><text  x="0" y="12" font-family="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" >A</text></svg>') left,
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 13 13"><text  x="0" y="12" font-family="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" >B</text></svg>') center,
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 13 13"><text  x="0" y="12" font-family="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" >C</text></svg>') right;
            mask-size:33% auto;
            mask-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<video src="https://node-images-test.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/Pexels+Videos+2292093.mp4" autoplay muted></video>
```

Answer (score 1):

In response to your video question, you can use `mix-blend-mode` with an overlay `div`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  mix-blend-mode: color-dodge;
}
```

```html
<video src="https://node-images-test.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/Pexels+Videos+2292093.mp4" autoplay muted></video>
<div class="overlay">
  S
</div>
```

Comment: thats some weird/cool css prop/effect, bit of play it seems `mix-blend-mode: screen;` or `mix-blend-mode: lighten;` works better

Comment: Good spot @LawrenceCherone. No problem newbie